# Does laravel reload classes on every call?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to loosely maintain persistent data between requests. Obviously a database is the best way to maintain data, but the exact correctness is extremely unimportant in this case.

I'm using a static variable in one of my controllers, but it appears to be reset on every request. Does laravel reload clases on every request?

Sample code:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
        public static $test = 0;


        public function getIndex() {
                LogHelper::info("TEST: " . HomeController::$test);
                HomeController::$test = HomeController::$test + 1;
                return View::make('layouts.home.index');
        }
}
```

this consistently logs 0 on every request. Is there a way to maintain a persistent variable without the use of a database?

EDIT: I need the variable to be the shared among all users/sessions. Like a hit counter.

Comment: use cache perhaps? or session

Comment: @Kyslik Someone made session as an answer, but that unfortunately doesn't work for me here. What's this cache solution?

Comment: Yes it does... laravel is simply a PHP script, that executes in the same way as any other PHP script... code terminates on completion of execution

Comment: @MarkBaker Okay, this is different from the way many other backend languages/frameworks operate.

Comment: It's the way PHP has worked for decades; each request executes in  a unique and self-contained thread, with no persistence unless you explicitly create it within your code via session, database, cache engine, filesystem, whatever

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not very familiar with PHP. Hence the question. Not sure of the reason for the sass. It's perfectly reasonable for me to ask this question having come from many other systems

Comment: You're interpreting it as sass: understanding how languages work should always be a precursor to using them, the PHP execution model is well documented, and works well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Laravel doesn't keep variables between requests and you need to persist your data manually by using sessions, DB etc.

For example, you can keep data using sessions:

```
session(['data' => $data]);
```

And get the data in next request:

```
$data = session('data');
```

**Update**

If you want to create some increasing costants, persist data to config files using one of many packages. Example of `/config/my.php` config:

```
<?php

return [
    'value' => 20,
];
```

Get this info from any part of the application:

```
$value = config('my.value');
```

Another way is to persist data in DB.

Comment: I should have made it clear that I want it constant for the entire application, and not on a user/session basis. I will edit

Comment: I meant that it needs to be the same for all users. Not constant as in unchanging. I have configuration files for that already. As stated in the edit to my question, the closest example would be a hit counter(that would reset to 0 on application restart).

Comment: @Cruncher if you need to use changing constant, use package for persisting data in config files or persist the data in DB.

Comment: It has to change at runtime... Consider the sample in the question. I need that value to increment by 1 everytime index is called. Regardless of by who, and session. If this isn't possible without a database then that's the answer I guess. But config is clearly not going to solve the problem stated in the question

Comment: Store in the database, or store it more temporarily in a `Cache` call.

Comment: @ceejayoz What's a cache call? If you have information on that, I'm sure it could qualify as an answer

Comment: @Cruncher You're going to really want to skim the entirety of Laravel's docs to get familiar with what it offers. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache

Comment: @Cruncher just go with DB, it's the most suitable way to work with data in your case.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Because of this, no data persists between subsequent requests to a web server unless pains are taken to make sure this data persists.

Every time you request a PHP script, PHP takes care to compile and load the PHP files requested and run them afresh. No data is retained in global or static variables and must be retrieved afresh to achieve the data state desired.
EDIT(strictly speaking, the byte code of compiled PHP files may be cached, it depends on the particulars of one's installation).

The most common means of giving a user a coherent experience in between page access is to use sessions. In any PHP script, you should be able to start the script with this:

```
session_start();
```

And then you can store values for subsequent pages accesses using the $_SESSION variables

```
$_SESSION['my_var'] = "some value";
```

On a subsequent page request, you have to call session_start again and then you should be able to retrieve the value stored in session:

```
session_start(); // gotta call this before setting/getting session values
echo "my_var is " . $_SESSION['my_var'];
```

Session handling is actually a fairly elaborate process that involves generating session ids, choosing a storage method, etc. For more detail, read the [php docs on session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

If you are using a particular framework (laravel in your case), you can make sure of custom [functions peculiar to that framework](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session) which can make things easier.